# How to turn urls padded by space into links

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have the following code that is used to turn http URLs in text into anchor tags. It's looking for anything starting with http, surrounded by white space (or the beginning/end of input)

```
function linkify (str) {
    var regex = /(^|\s)(https?:\/\/\S+)($|\s)/ig;
    return str.replace(regex,'$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$3')
}

// This works
linkify("Go to http://www.google.com and http://yahoo.com");

// This doesn't, yahoo.com doesn't become a link
linkify("Go to http://www.google.com http://yahoo.com");
```

The case where it doesn't work is if I only have a single space between two links. I'm assuming it's because the space in between the two links can't be used to match both URLs, after the first match, the space after the URL has already been consumed.

To play with: http://jsfiddle.net/NgMw8/

Can somebody suggest a regex way of doing this? I could scan the string myself, looking for a regex way of doing it (or some way that doesn't require scanning the string my self and building a new string on my own.

Comment: Why do you start with whitespace? Why not have your regex pattern start with http and end with the first whitespace match it finds. Then your second link will be matched because it contains http until a space is matched.

Comment: @Mark Because I don't want "youhttp://ww.google.com to become a link"

Comment: In that case, you would not be part of the link. http://www.google.com would and you would just be a string before the link. I think this would be a more accurate way of finding valid links.

Comment: @Mark, I mostly agree, but if you look at this comment, XXXhttp://www.google didn't become a link. And this is how it's specified to be implemented

Comment: True, but there is room for improving what others have done. If someone were to fatfinger a comment and forget to put a space between 'click here' and the url, no reason why we can't match on the url if we know its valid because it contains a protocol, a domain, and a TLD. The real challenge is knowing if the url contains a TLD.

Comment: @Mark Like I said, I agree. I was more interested in understanding how it could be achieved, but notice that SO chose not to implement it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't capture the final `\s`. This way, the second url will match the preceding `\s`, as required:

```
function linkify (str) {
    var regex = /(^|\s)(https?:\/\/\S+)/ig;
    return str.replace(regex,'$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>')
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NgMw8/3/

Comment: I don not want something like XXXhttp://www.google.com to become a link, just like it didn't become one in this comment

Comment: @JuanMendes: I see, please check my edit. Also, why do you need `$3`? You can just put a whitespace in the replace.

Comment: If I remove the final \s, then something like http://google.comXXX will become a link. The $3 is just to add back whatever was following the url. Mmmm.... maybe not... checking

Comment: That's right, there's no need to capture the final space. Thanks João.

Comment: @JuanMendes: But that's what your current regex already does. To stop it from doing so, you'd have to add more complexity to your regex, to match top level domains (tld), such as `\.(com|org|net)` etc. Otherwise, there's no way for you to know with just `\S+`, if `.comXXX` or `.net` is a valid tld.

Comment: I got it, couldn't use TLD since I want the entire URL, not just the host, but what you suggested is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Just use a positive lookahead when matching your final `$|\s`, like so:

```
var regex = /(^|\s)(https?:\/\/\S+)(?=($|\s))/ig;
```

Comment: Nice, but as João pointed out, there's no need to have the `($|\s)` at the end since the last component of the regex is a `\S+`

Answer (score 0):

None will work if there are any html element stuck to the url ...

Similar question and it's answers [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440232/using-regex-and-javascript-to-make-links-clickable-but-not-overwrite-pre-existin/12446278#answer-12446278)

Some solutions can handle url like "test.com/anothertest?get=letsgo" and append http://

- Workaround may be done to handle https and miscellaneous tld ...

Comment: Not sure what you're saying... my question was specifically about urls padded by spaces. The link you posted is not about what I asked.

Comment: well it deals with handling padded urls that have to be turned into a link tag, url can be prefixed with http prefix or not and can be nested in html, ... I thought it could help ...