# Using regex and javascript to make links clickable but not overwrite pre-existing links?

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperlink, clickable

I need to make links clickable using javascript and I thought regex would be the easiest not to mention fastest way. I want all links to be clickable, and to not rewrite the already clickable links that exist.

```
Example: 
Here is a link to visit http://www.example.com/page Please take a look <a href="http://www.example.com/page">here</a>.

Becomes: Here is a link to visit <a href="http://www.example.com/page">http://www.example.com/page</a> Please take a look <a href="http://www.example.com/page">here</a>.

Another example: Here is a link to visit http://www.example.com/page Please take a look here: <a href="http://www.example.com/page">http://www.example.com/page</a>

Becomes: Here is a link to visit <a href="http://www.example.com/page">http://www.example.com/page</a> Please take a look here: <a href="http://www.example.com/page">http://www.example.com/page</a>

And finally: <p id="demo">http://example.com/
<br><a href="http://example.com/123">http://example.com/123</a>
<br><a href="http://Google.ca/">http://Google.ca/</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("[^\"'](http://[^ ]*)","g");
var newContent = yourString.replace(pattern," <a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```

To tace care of the comment:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("([^\"'])(http://[^ ]*)","g");
var newContent = yourString.replace(pattern,"$1<a href=\"$2\">$2</a>");
```

One more edit after comment, the previous one asumed the link was not at the beginning:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("([^\"']||^)(http://[^ ]*)","g");
var newContent = yourString.replace(pattern,"$1<a href=\"$2\">$2</a>");
```

You have probably seen the pattern already, in regular expressions what is inside () are asigned to a return parameter $1 and $2 in this case, witch is is used in the replace statement to rebuild the string.. The pattern here must probably be extended further as you come across other exceptions not catched by the pattern, for instance putting the link inside () would not give the desired result. A nice site to play with regular expressions is [regextester.com](http://regextester.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't exactly work when dealing with it in a situation as follows: 
<p id="demo">http://example.com/
<br><a href="http://example.com/123">http://example.com/123</a>
<br><a href="http://Google.ca/">http://Google.ca/</a></p>

Comment: Here's a jiffidle example of the situation I'm in. http://jsfiddle.net/WRjsX/3/
Using the regex provided, I think I'm doing something wrong but I just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = [
        "http://www.example.com/page address at the begining then a well formated a tag take a look <a href='http://www.example.com/page'>here</a>.",
        " text in front http://www.example.com/page Please take a look <a href='http://www.example.com/page'>here</a>.",
        "  http less with get vars www.example.com/page?foo=bar Please take a look  <a href='http://www.example.com/page'>here</a>.",
        '<p>http://example.com/<br /><a href="http://example.com/123">http://example.com/123</a><br /><a href="http://Google.ca/">http://Google.ca/</a></p>'
    ] ,
    reg = /([\s>]|^)((?:http:\/\/)?(?:[a-z][\w-]+)+(?:\.[\w-]+)*(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})(?:[^ <]+))(?=[\s<]|$)/g,
    output = '';
    for(var key in text){
        $('body').append(
        '<div>'+
          text[key]
                .replace(reg, '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>')
                .replace(/(href=['"])(?!http:\/\/)/g, '$1http://')+
        '</pre>'
        );
    }
```

Can be tested in browser/Firebug console.

More tests should be done to find the most trusted extremis delimiters/markers

Comment: Your test + mine jsfiddle.net/AeZ37/